# I want to corrupt a swf ... then "uncorrupt" to make it a valid swf.. is it Possible? Android Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, tablet

Im trying to do something like this: 
Take an swf file corrupt it, Then ..inside the device turn it readable (not corrupted)again ... I´ll check, with a device-finger-print writen by myself, if that device can uncorrupt the swf.. got?

Can I do this? what is the way? Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires File I/O

encrypt the swf with like base64 or anything and append any random string to the beginning or end of the file, save it somewhere, and de-encrypt it when you want to use it

Comment: Yes, and go make him a sandwich.

Comment: Ok CQM.. I'll try it and if works I'll check your answer thankyou! monday

Answer (score 1):

There are of course many ways make reversible changes the contents of an swf file so that it is not playable by other players until the changes are reversed. At the minimum, you could reverse its 3 byte signature to make it unplayable and reverse it again.

But any such naive mechanism you employ can be cracked very easily. It will *not* protect you from any malicious activity and will only inconvenience legitimate usage.

If you really need to do this, look at more sophisticated encryption and DRM

Comment: +1 for recommending a better approach (encryption) than "breaking" and "unbreaking" a file.